# Drupal 7 Trying to create a "Today in History" view

Tags: views, database

I'm sure there's an easy way to do the following but I've not come up with a safe Drupal way to do so:

My current front page has a view which generates a list of the most recent three articles on my site using the date stored in  field_published attached to each article. The SQL which the view generates looks like this:

`SELECT field_data_field_published.field_published_value AS field_data_field_published_field_published_value, node.nid AS nid FROM node node LEFT JOIN field_data_field_published field_data_field_published ON node.nid = field_data_field_published.entity_id AND (field_data_field_published.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_published.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (node.status = '1') )) ORDER BY field_data_field_published_field_published_value DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;`

( You can see what this looks like live on my [website](http://kanthanpillay.com) )

Running the query on mysql CLI generates this:

`+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
| field_data_field_published_field_published_value | nid |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
| 2017-01-23 00:00:00                              | 427 |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00                              | 426 |
| 2016-08-07 00:00:00                              | 424 |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+`

I want to now create a similar view that searches only the month and day field of every article in the DB, matches the month and day against 'today', and generates a list of article nid. The SQL for this is:

`SELECT field_data_field_published.field_published_value AS field_data_field_published_field_published_value, node.nid AS nid FROM node node LEFT JOIN field_data_field_published field_data_field_published ON node.nid = field_data_field_published.entity_id AND field_data_field_published.entity_type = 'node' WHERE (( (field_data_field_published.field_published_value LIKE (select date_format(curdate(),'____-%m-%d%'))) )) AND (( (node.status = '1') ))
ORDER BY field_data_field_published_field_published_value DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;`

This correctly generates a list of article nid on the CLI:

`+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
| field_data_field_published_field_published_value | nid |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
| 2015-05-24 00:00:00                              | 369 |
| 1999-05-24 00:00:00                              | 222 |
| 1997-05-24 00:00:00                              | 150 |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+`

My question is, how do I get my functional SQL statement into a view?

I have tried using Views Contextual Filters and Granularity, but that does not allow me to omit the year when filtering dates.

I have tried to use hook views_pre_execute in a module but it barfs on my query: Something like

`<?php
// TMG 3-21-09
// call to hook_views_pre_execute to override the query for the groups browser
function views_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
   if($view->name=="future_front_page2") {
       $kp_tih = date('____-m-d%');
       $view->build_info['query']="SELECT field_data_field_published.field_pub
lished_value AS field_data_field_published_field_published_value, node.nid AS ni
d FROM node node LEFT JOIN field_data_field_published field_data_field_published
 ON node.nid = field_data_field_published.entity_id AND field_data_field_publish
ed.entity_type = 'node' WHERE (( (field_data_field_published.field_published_val
ue LIKE (select date_format(curdate(),'____-%m-%d%'))) )) AND (( (node.status = 
'1') )) ORDER BY field_data_field_published_field_published_value DESC LIMIT 3 O
FFSET 0";
       $query = db_select('node','n')->addTag('node_access');
       drupal_set_message(t($query));`

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x).

Even though, I think you can do it using only views without altering the query.
Maybe using Date Views module would help.

Comment: I started off trying hook_views_query_alter but it similarly rejected the date calc in the SQL. Unable to find the Date Views module. Pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the select at 'select date_format'. A similar query is : (DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_field.created), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)), '%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-04-04'). If you want to add this module try to enable it using drush. drush en date_views -y